# Python function return None. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
count = []

def problem14(n):
    count.append(n)
    if n == 1:
        return count
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n/2
        problem14(n)
    else:
        n = 3*n + 1
        problem14(n)


print problem14(13)
```

So this is code that I have written. I have no idea why it's returning None while in my opinion it should return list 'count'. Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You still need a return statement when using recursion, otherwise the return value will be lost:

```
def problem14(n):
    count.append(n)
    if n == 1:
        return count
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n/2
        return problem14(n)  # <--
    else:
        n = 3*n + 1
        return problem14(n)  # <--
```

By the way, this is probably the wrong approach for Project Euler #14 :-) Consider using a [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach instead (that's all I'll say so as to not ruin the fun).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the return keyword in order to `return` a value from a function.

```
return problem14(n)
```